# If one event happens in an interval according to a Poisson process, how to calculate the expected value of when it occurred?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, means, poisson-process

I have a Poisson Process. I have been told that one event has happened in a 30 second interval. How do I calculate the expected value of the random variable for the time until the event occurs within my interval?

(expected value for the event is 1 per 5 minutes if that's relevant)

Comment: You can use the fact that if we condition on having exactly $k$ arrivals in an interval $[0,t]$ for a Poisson process, their locations are iid and uniformly distributed over the interval.  Or you can compute a conditional distribution $F_{X_1|A}(y) = P[X_1\leq y|X_1 \leq 30, X_2>30-X_1]$ for $y \in [0, 30]$, where $A = \{X_1\leq30, X_2>30-X_1\}$.

Comment: That helps me find the probability of an event occurring during some interval, but I don't see how that helps for the expected value.

Comment: The whole 'being uniformly distributed' is what is confusing me, as the expected value is supposed to be the value most likely to happen, but any instant is equally likely.

Comment: Do you know how to compute the expected value of a random variable $X$ with a general PDF $f_X(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$? Or for a random variable $X$ that is uniformly distributed over the interval $[0, 8]$?